# Screen flicker, blink, pulse, flash

Tags: release-freya, display, desktop, graphics

Anyone experiencing random screen flicker, blink, pulse, flashing when on single and dual monitor, or opening multiple windows at once?

OS & VERSION
elementary OS 0.3 Freya (64-bit)

HARDWARE
Sony Vaio Laptop (2006)
Processor: Dual-Core Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU     T6400  @ 2.00GHz
Graphics: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)

Comment: Any chance you could record a video of the issue, either by screencapping of actually filming the monitor(s)? That might help people identify your problem.

Comment: I can try.  It's so random.  But, I will try

Comment: I have a similar laptop (VAIO VGN-NR120E) and I have the same problem

Answer (score 4):

If you have an intel graphic chip, you could try comment nr 5
[Screen flickering solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1435861)

Comment: This worked for me. After that change sometimes my screen freezes or crashes suddenly. (very rarely, not that annoying like the flickering)

Comment: My mothers laptop (dell with intel graphicchip) had the same problems and this answer from launchpad worked great. No problems anymore.

Comment: Worked for my Sony Vaio VGN-NR120E