# Screen shake issue with Dell Inspiron 11

Tags: release-freya

Just bought a new Dell Inspiron 3162 11 inch (http://www.dell.com/au/p/inspiron-11-3162-laptop/pd?ref=PD_OC), and tried to install my first linux distro. I got this weird screen shaking (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mz1sXXtssXA).

I haven't committed to a full install, and I just want to make sure this issue is fixable before I overwrite my drive. I was running a live USB with Elementary OS in the video, and I've tried Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 15.10 with the same shake. Ubuntu MATE has no shaking issue, but once I start my webcam, the shakes start. Lubuntu seems to be the only distro where there is no shaking, but I'm not 100% certain.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to fix the issue by running these commands in Terminal after you install Elementary OS:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
echo -e 'Section "Device"\n Identifier "Intel Graphics"\n Driver "Intel"\n Option "AccelMethod" "sna"\n Option "TearFree" "true"\nEndSection' | sudo tee /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
sudo reboot
```

Source: comment #5 in [this ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1435861), as well as [this Stack Exchange question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/screen-flicker-blink-pulse-flash).